Mean-field theory extra term
In mean-field theory, the electron-electron Hamiltonian is approximated by a sum of mean values of the creation/annihilation operators. I tried to derive that result but obtained an extra term. How can I get rid of it?
$\begin{aligned} c_\mu^{\dagger} c_\nu^{\dagger} c_{\nu^{\prime}} c_{\mu^{\prime}} & =\delta_{\nu \nu^{\prime}} c_\mu^{\dagger} c_{\mu^{\prime}}-c_\mu^{\dagger} c_{\nu^{\prime}} c_\nu^{\dagger} c_{\mu^{\prime}} \\ & =c_{\nu^{\prime}} c_\nu^{\dagger} c_\mu^{\dagger} c_{\mu^{\prime}}+c_\nu^{\dagger} c_{\nu^{\prime}} c_\mu^{\dagger} c_{\mu^{\prime}}-c_\mu^{\dagger} c_{\nu^{\prime}} c_\nu^{\dagger} c_{\mu^{\prime}} \\ & \simeq\left\langle c_\nu^{\dagger} c_{\nu^{\prime}}\right\rangle c_\mu^{\dagger} c_{\mu^{\prime}}+\left\langle c_\mu^{\dagger} c_{\mu^{\prime}}\right\rangle c_\nu^{\dagger} c_{\nu^{\prime}}-\left\langle c_\nu^{\dagger} c_{\nu^{\prime}}\right\rangle\left\langle c_\mu^{\dagger} c_{\mu^{\prime}}\right\rangle \\ & -\left\langle c_\mu^{\dagger} c_{\nu^{\prime}}\right\rangle c_\nu^{\dagger} c_{\mu^{\prime}}-\left\langle c_\nu^{\dagger} c_{\mu^{\prime}}\right\rangle c_\mu^{\dagger} c_{\nu^{\prime}}+\left\langle c_\mu^{\dagger} c_{\nu^{\prime}}\right\rangle\left\langle c_\nu^{\dagger} c_{\mu^{\prime}}\right\rangle \\ & +c_{\nu^{\prime}} c_\nu^{\dagger} c_\mu^{\dagger} c_{\mu^{\prime}}\end{aligned}$

Which term are you calling the «extra term» ?

the last one. as far as i know the usual result doesnt have it

The last term, $c_{\nu'}c_{\nu}^\dagger c_{\mu}^\dagger c_{\mu'}$, can be neglected in the approximation because we set the «deviation» squared to zero.
What does this mean? If we look at the simple Hartee mean field approximation, where we have two particles described by operators $a_\nu$ and $b_\mu$ respectively, then the operators in the interaction term are $a_\nu^\dagger b_\mu^\dagger b_{\mu'} a_{\nu'}$. The same way we approximate a curve as: $$f(x)\approx (x-x_0)f'(x_0)+f(x_0)$$ or $$(x-x_0)f'(x_0)\approx f(x)-f(x_0)$$
which is a better approximation when $x$ is «close» to $x_0$ for a smooth function, $f$, we can also have: $$g_{\nu\nu'}:=a_\nu^\dagger a_{\nu'}-\left<a_\nu^\dagger a_{\nu'}\right>$$
$$h_{\mu\mu'}:=b_\mu^\dagger b_{\mu'}-\left<b_\mu^\dagger b_{\mu'}\right>$$
In this form, we set $g_{\nu\nu'}h_{\mu\mu'}$ to zero since it is the «deviation» squared (analogous to us setting $(x-x_0)(y-y_0)$ to zero in a first-order approximation around the point $\mathbf{r}_0:=(x_0,y_0)$).
If you extend this to the Hartee-Fock mean field approximation, you can set the deviations squared to zero to remove the final term. i.e., $\left(c_\nu^\dagger c_{\nu'}-\left<c_\nu^\dagger c_{\nu'}\right>\right)\left(c_\mu^\dagger c_{\mu'}-\left<c_\mu^\dagger c_{\mu'}\right>\right)\rightarrow0$.
Edit:
$$c_\mu^\dagger c_\nu^\dagger c_{\nu'}  c_{\mu'}=c_\mu^\dagger\left(c_\nu^\dagger c_{\nu'}-\left<c_\nu^\dagger c_{\nu'}\right>\right)c_{\mu'}+c_\mu^\dagger c_{\mu'}\left<c_\nu^\dagger c_{\nu'}\right>$$
Do the same thing for the other terms: $$c_\mu^\dagger c_\nu^\dagger c_{\nu'}  c_{\mu'}=\left(c_\mu^\dagger c_{\mu'}-\left<c_\mu^\dagger c_{\mu'}\right>\right)\left(c_\nu^\dagger c_{\nu'}-\left<c_\nu^\dagger c_{\nu'}\right>\right)+c_\mu^\dagger c_{\mu'}\left<c_\nu^\dagger c_{\nu'}\right>+c_\nu^\dagger c_{\nu'}\left<c_\mu^\dagger c_{\mu'}\right>-\left<c_\nu^\dagger c_{\nu'}\right>\left<c_\mu^\dagger c_{\mu'}\right>$$
The first term goes to zero, then you add this term with the Fock/exchange term.

how is it proportional to the deviation squared?

@RichHardFineMan see the last line of my answer

im looking at it but its not obvious to me how you go from this extra term to that. can you elaborate please?

@RichHardFineMan See the «Edit» section

im sorry if im missing your point, but i think that what you did is what i tried to do too, the only difference being that i didnt assume the terms commute. in order to group mu and mu' you had to assume that the respective operator commutes with nu and nu', which may not be true. moreover, i think that only its only possible to obtain the fock term when you dont make that assumption and expand the kronecker delta, in my first line on the right side

@RichHardFineMan Sure, then you look at the case when $\mu'$ equals $\nu$ and this gives you the remaining terms as the Fock term. The same procedure will get rid of any two-particle operators.

by that is what i did no? what do you suggest i do differently?
